# Additional Media Types for Spring Data Rest Repository Controllers

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, json-ld

Trying to add the JSON-LD serialisation provided by the project Hydra Java to an application using Spring Data Rest and the controllers generated by @RepositoryRestResource

While I've been able to serialize as JSON-LD using manually created @RepositoryRestController using the application/ld+json media type, I'm unable to do the same for the controllers generated for the repositories annotated as RepositoryRest Resource. They seem to just accept application/json and application/hal+json

Is it possible to configure these controllers to also accept additional media types?

This is how I've configured the [HydraMessageConverter](https://github.com/dschulten/hydra-java/blob/master/hydra-spring/src/main/java/de/escalon/hypermedia/spring/hydra/HydraMessageConverter.java) provided by the Hydra Java project:

```
    @Bean
    public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer()
    {
        return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void configureHttpMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
                messageConverters.add(0, new HydraMessageConverter());
                super.configureHttpMessageConverters(messageConverters);
            }
         }
    }
```